# django behind subdomain on localhost with nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, localhost, subdomain

I have a django project which I want to display diferent content according to the subdomain it's being accessed, for example, when a user enters to url: http://e1.example.com/ it displays **«Welcome to e1 site»**, when user enters to: http://e2.example.com it displays **«Welcome to e2 site»** and so on.

So I have this nginx configuration:

```
upstream example_project{
    server localhost:8200;
}

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name ~^(?<event>.+)\.example\.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example_project/$event$request_uri;
    }
}
```

and I have my `/etc/hosts` file like following:

```
127.0.0.1   example.com
127.0.0.1   e1.example.com
127.0.0.1   e2.example.com
```

when I go to `http://localhost:8200/e1/` it works, but when I go to `http://e1.example.com/` it shows a **400 error**

On django console output I have:

```
[18/Aug/2014 14:33:31] "GET /e1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 39 <-- this when going localhost:8200/e1/
[18/Aug/2014 14:33:33] "GET /e1/ HTTP/1.0" 400 26 <-- this when going e1.example.com
```

So I can see `e1.example.com` is calling my project correct URL, but why does the browser show me a 400 error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I realized that I have to put more proxy parameters to nginx, now I have my nginx configuration with:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://example_project/$event$request_uri;
}
```

end everythnig works like desired.
Maybe this could help anyone who is going to do something similar. :)